# Logarithm bounded by polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, logarithms

Let $x,y > 0$. Does there exist a polynomial $P(x,y)$ such that $\log_{1+\frac{1}{x}}(y)\le P(x,y)$ for all $x,y$?

We can write $\log_{1+\frac{1}{x}}(y)$ as $\frac{\log y}{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}$, but which bound can we use from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since $\log y < y$ and $\frac{1}{\log(1+\tfrac{1}{x})} < 1+x$ for all $x,y>0$.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = \log(1+\tfrac{1}{x}) - \frac{1}{1+x}$ for $x>0$. It's strictly decreasing ($f'(x)<0$) and it's limit at $\infty$ is $0$, so we have $f(x)> 0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: @tarthoe A simpler way using the mean value: $\log(1+\tfrac{1}{x}) = \log(x+1) - \log(x) = \frac{1}{\xi} > \frac{1}{x+1}$ since $x < \xi < x+1$